# NGINX getting an application in a subfolder to work with redirects

Tags: nginx, directory

I've installed [Mautic](https://www.mautic.org/) in a subfolder like: `example.com/m`
Most of Mautic is working fine with my configuration (admin panel, using Mautic etc.) but for some redirects in my subfolder, I get a `404`:

```
example.com/m 200
example.com/m/form/9 200
example.com/m/form/generate.js?id=9 404
```

(/form doesn't exist - it should be redirected/generated by Mautic dynamically)

All files on the file system belong to www-data.

My nginx conf for the host:

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    rewrite_log on;

    root /var/www/example.com/www.example.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com_error.log notice;

    #######################################
    ##  Start Mautic Specific config #####
    #######################################

    location /m {
        # Working despite forms:
        try_files $uri $uri/ /m/?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    #######################################
    ##  End Mautic Specific config #####
    #######################################

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }

    # A long browser cache lifetime can speed up repeat visits to your page
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|webp|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
       access_log        off;
       log_not_found     off;
       expires           360d;
    }

    # disable access to hidden files
    location ~ /\.ht {
      access_log off;
      log_not_found off;
      deny all;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/stats.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/stats.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/stats.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/stats.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;

}

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    #return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|webp|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|css|js|ico|xml)$` block is handling the URI that ends with `.js`. You could try moving that block inside the `location /` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want URIs that begin with `/m` to be handled by the `location /m` block.

However, regular expression locations take precedence, so the URI `/m/form/generate.js` is actually being handled by another location that matches all URIs that end with `.js`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

There is the `^~` operator which forces the prefix location to take precedence, but that will not work in your case, as the application is PHP, and you need URIs that end with `.php` to be handled by the `location ~ \.php$` block.

So instead, I suggest you nest the `location` causing the problem within the `location /` block.

For example:

```
location /m {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /m/?q=$uri&$args;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|webp|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
        access_log        off;
        log_not_found     off;
        expires           360d;
    }
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    ...
}
```